# Accents on numbers in HTML (like a ^ over 1)

Tags: html, css, special-characters, diacritics

I'm trying to find the best way to put circumflex accents ( ˆ = `&circ;`) on top of numbers (a musical notation) without resorting to images. Certain letters have equivalent HTML entities: ê = `&ecirc;`, Ô = `&Ocirc;`, etc., but numbers don't.

Here is what I'm currently using on my [website](http://carillontech.org/vademecum/):

```
<span style="position:relative;">1
   <span style="position:absolute; 
                left:0.1em; 
                bottom:0.2em; 
                font-size:1.1em;">
                &circ; 
   </span>  
</span>
```

It looks pretty good, but not perfect---because of slight differences in number shapes and browser rendering, something is bound to be a little off.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution for this?

**Update:**

The Combining Circumflex Accent `&#770;` or `&#x302;` produces different results on different browsers/platforms, most of which are not right (on my Mac, only Safari does it right).

According to [this](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#12b), proper display of a combining accent is dependent on both the font and the renderer. I'm using `Times New Roman, Times`, so it doesn't appear to be a workable option. I can't afford the hassle and inevitable ignoring of requiring a user to have a particular font.

I guess I'll have to stick with manually positioning the accent atop the note as above unless there's any other new answers.  Thanks.

**Update 2:**

Embedding a free font with better diacritic support (especially [Doulos SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&cat_id=FontDownloadsDoulos)) seemed promising, but as of now (Nov 2009), Chrome does not support `@font-face` in CSS by default. Once it does, though, it will be great, since the other browsers are already on board. [webfonts.info](http://www.webfonts.info) is the place for info on this.

Comment: If you're gonna try them seperately, you might find this firefox addon to be usefull: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5235

Comment: Have you ever stopped and thought that maybe this doesn't work because there aren't any character sets anywhere that have the circumflex access over numbers?

Comment: I think that you should take another approach in this case, maybe using MathML. These are not real characters (are not included in Unicode set). In your case you have a very simple form of an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rendering of the combining mark isn't sufficiently good I guess you would have to hack it up with positioning.

```
<style>
    .over { position: relative; }
    .over span { position: absolute; top: -0.5em; left: 0; }
</style>

abc <span class="over">1<span>^</span></span> xyz
```

Still a nasty hack! But possibly less work than MathML.

Comment: will using em for positioning give a better result than px in this case?  What's this about MathML? I've never used it.

Comment: Using em for positioning will work better, as it will work even when the user is enlarging text in his browser. It's best to always use either px or a relative unit but never to mix them, so that the distances stay consistent.

Comment: MathML support in browsers is still pretty sketchy, and usually requires a lot of work on the end user's part. But MathML could render it with something like <mover><mi>^</mi><mi>1</mi></mover>

Answer (score 8):

[`U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT`](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=combining+circumflex)

Make one with character map or with the entity

```
 &#x302;
```

Stick one over anything you want by putting it after it:

> `e&#x302; A&#x302; 1&#x302;` [image: :)]`&#x302;`

Becomes

> ê  Â  1̂  [image: :)]̂

...but it's not designed to go over the 1 or the smiley face. Notice how it moved up higher for the A but not for the 1 or the smiley face.

Comment: thanks.  Yeah, unfortunately it doesn't display consistently across browsers. On my mac, it works great on Safari, but not on Chrome (which is weird since it's also WebKit), Firefox, or Opera. On everything but Safari, it just puts the accent next to the number/letter, as if it were the next character in line.

Comment: @carillonator: That is odd, since I'm also using Chrome for Mac and it looks terrible but is indeed above the number rather than next to it.

Comment: @Chuck: With Mac Chrome, in this post the accent covers up the top of the 1, but when I make a separate html file with only this stuff in it, Chrome puts the accent next to it.

Comment: can we channel that hatred toward internet explorer and make it go away? the world will be a better place.

Comment: On Safari 4.0.3 on OS X leopard I see a square box next to the "1" and the smiley face.  I guess that it  doesn't work for my setup for some reason.

Comment: It's primarily a font issue I think, rather than browsers per se — although browsers complicate the issue by having different default fonts. If your font has a glyph available for A-with-circumflex you should get that, otherwise you'll get a separate A and circumflex fudged together. ...that is, if you even have a glyph for a standalone circumflex. If you don't, you'll get the browser's replacement character symbol (a box or question mark).

Answer (score 4):

Try the *COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT* (U+0302) using `&#770;` or `&#x302;`:

```
1&#770;
```

Example:

> 1̂

Answer (score 2):

A lot will depend on whether or not the font your user is using supports this feature. Since you cannot embed fonts in a web page (without some potential legal trouble), your best bet is to try the above suggestions with different fonts to determine if the character your looking for is supported. Once you find a font, reference it in your CSS file and then inform the user that a specific font is required to correctly view your site.

Try using the following unicode index: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm

You will need to know the name of the character you are trying to display. Once you've found it, the information page will tell you how to display the character using HTML character codes.

Comment: You can always embed free and open source fonts though .. there are more than you'd imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [combining diacritical marks](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#12b) faq. A combining circumflex is U+0302.

That section says: "Some fonts, such as the Doulos and Charis fonts, which are freely available for download, contain large repertoires of appropriate precomposed glyphs". It might be worth a try to get your users to download those fonts (if they work).

You might have some success shrinking the number:

```
<span style="font-size: 75%">1</span>&#x0302;
```